# For the matrix A = 2 0 1; 0 −1 0 ;1 0 2, find an orthogonal matrix P such that tP AP = D, where D is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&1\\0 &-1&0\\1&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$
 find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^t AP = D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix
I got $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\0 &1&0\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\0 &-1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
However, I am not able to verify the formula $P^tAP=D$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @Divya: Latex advice: In OP $P$ and $D$ are looks fine but $A$ is not. So edit properly **otherwise appreciate other user edits**. You can use other user edits rather than deleting other edits!

Comment: With all due respect sir, I did not delete any edits. I missed it by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you start from 
$$AU=U.diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$$ where $\lambda_i$ represents the i-th biggest eigenvalue, and U is a matrix where the i-th column represents the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

$$U^{-1}AU=U^{-1}U.diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$$
$$U^{-1}AU=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$$

but $U^{-1}=U^T$ just if U is an **orthogonal matrix** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)

To make U orthogonal, consider normalize the eigenvectors, i.e. divide them by their norm. You'll obtain the matrix that our colleague has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The $P$ which you have chosen is not orthogonal since it fails to satisfy $P^TP = I$. Note that the columns of $P$ should be mutually orthogonal and of length $1$.

Instead, you can use
$$
P = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & -1/\sqrt{2}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2}}
$$